# unable to test iOS application in kobiton

Tags: manual-testing, ios

We are using Kobiton paid subscription to test android and iOS applications. While testing iOS application, asking a password for an Apple account.

How can I proceed with the testing on iOS devices?

Comment: Fill in a correct password? Or why is this not a solution?

Comment: You shouldn't need to enter a password.  Do all iOS devices in their device farm do this ?  It is possible that the specific device you are using is misconfigured.  Or the IPA you are testing is not properly enabled for automation.  Probably best to contact Kobiton.